# selecting pixels randomly and uniformly

Tags: matlab

I have grey image divided into patches, I need to select pixels from each patches randomly and uniformly, so the method of selection should be the same for all patches..
the uniform pixel selection is critical in my project as I will need to find intensities difference between each two pixels.
here is the code that I try but it does not give the required result as only 8 pixels is selected where the patches size are [90 X 100]

```
    I = imread('0001hv1.bmp');
Rpix = zeros(size(I));
[m n] = size(I);
for i = 2:m-1
  for j = 2:n-1
  switch randi(8,1,1)
    case 1
        rpix1 = I(i-1,j-1);
    case 2
        rpix2 = I(i-1,j);
    case 3
        rpix3 = I(i-1,j+1);
    case 4
        rpix4 = I(i,j-1);
    case 5
        rpix5 = I(i,j+1);  %skip i,j as that is the pixel itself
    case 6
        rpix6 = I(i+1,j-1);
    case 7
        rpix7 = I(i+1,j);
    case 8
        rpix8 = I(i+1,j+1);
  end
  %rpix(i,j) = rpix ; 

 end
end
im_sub1 = rpix1 - rpix2;
im_sub2 = rpix3 - rpix4;
im_sub3 = rpix5 - rpix6;
im_sub4 = rpix7- rpix8;
```

I read about Gaussian distribution where the idea proposed is:" X and Y are randomly sampled using a Gaussian distribution where first X is sampled with a standard deviation of 0.04*S^2 and then the Yi’s are sampled using a Gaussian distribution – Each Yi is sampled with mean Xi and standard deviation of 0.01 * S^2."

is it suitable to my code case and how can I implement it ?
thank you

Comment: Do you know this algorithm for equidistant random distribution? http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/dbb02448b0f93e4c82c3

Comment: You don't save any of`rpix1,2,..,8` in the loop, so you only get the `8` values from the last loop.

Comment: Your idea is correct, Gauss is not what you want, but it seems you have an implementation problem. As Kamtal mentioned, what is it with the rpix1..rpix8? Shouldn't they be decoupled from the randomization process?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is fill a 1x8 matrix with random values, then use these as indices. The indices need  then be mapped to the real x,y values. Be careful to use a one-dimensional index first. Because you have a hole at the center, uniformity would be a problem if you would use random x,y values.

Comment: could you please clarify how can I map random value to real X, Y by example. thank you